# Which court to challenge the reply from the UK prime minister?

Tags: united-kingdom, freedom-of-information

Picture from a tweet: https://twitter.com/RussellScott1/status/1717914808803070309

*(1.8K retweets)*

[image]

I would like to challenge the reply from PM and insist that dislosing information is in public interest - I'm just unsure which court should handle this matter?

Answer (score 3):

The UK Law (Freedom of Information Act 2000) has a defined [appeals process](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2000/36/part/V).

> Appeal against notices served under Part IV. (1)Where a decision
> notice has been served, the complainant or the public authority may
> appeal to the Tribunal against the notice.

The venue is a Tribunal, specifically the [First-tier Tribunal (General Regulatory Chamber)](https://www.gov.uk/courts-tribunals/first-tier-tribunal-general-regulatory-chamber).

Comment: I'm afraid this is not quite right, because the route is longer. First, one would complain to the Cabinet Office and ask for an internal review. If that is unsatisfactory then one can refer it to the ICO, who would issue a "decision notice". Only then is there an appeal to the FTT.